# SoftDeleteInterceptor generates invalid WHERE clause

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I'm currently working with Entity Framework and MySql provider. Also using SoftDeleteInterceptor to filter data. The easiest way to show my problem is this example:

```
context.GetQuery(m => m.AnyColumn == true || m.Name != "Test").ToList();
```

This is translated to:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM `Table` AS `Extent1` 
WHERE 
    (1 = `Extent1`.`AnyCOlumn`) OR 
    ((('Test' = `Extent1`.`Name`) AND (`Extent1`.`Name` IS NOT NULL))) AND 
    `Extent1`.`Deleted` != 1;
```

I replaced all columns in `Select to *`, because it's not the part of this question. My question is, why there is no parenthesis over `OR` expression, so `AND` from Soft Delete could be used. Because when left part of `OR` is true, other conditions are skipped. How to fix this? Or how to add parenthesis? Any suggestions?

Comment: Where did you get SoftDeleteInterceptor?

Comment: What if you do `m.AnyColumn == true | m.Name != "Test"` ?? It looks like it placed parenthesis in the wrong place

Comment: In SQL `Name <> 'Test'` is NOT true if `Name` is NULL. Comparisons with NULL are *always* false. Apart from that, If `SoftDeleteInterceptor`, whatever that is, does *NOT* surround the **ENTIRE** condition with parentheses, *it* has a bug. Simply appending a `AND Deleted != 1 ` at the end of a condition works only in very specific cases because AND has precedence over OR

Comment: @T.S. EF put the parentheses where it should. It's the `AND 
    Extent1.Deleted != 1;` that causes the problem, not the parentheses

Comment: @Ado googling for `SoftDeleteInterceptor` returns different libraries that *set* a Deleted field. None *filters* by it though. And `GetQuery` isn't a DbContext method. What does `GetQuery` do and what is `SoftDeleteInterceptor`? It's not possible to help with code or library issues if you don't post the code or at least a link to the library

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sure. Here `((('Test' = `Extent1`.`Name`) AND (`Extent1`.`Name` IS NOT NULL)))` it has extra set. Could be `(('Test' = `Extent1`.`Name`) AND (`Extent1`.`Name` IS NOT NULL))`. so, the question is, what added this extra set, EF or "Interceptor"

Comment: @T.S. EF wouldn't add extra parentheses. Even if it did, there would be no problem if that `Deleted !=1` wasn't added. Maybe the `Interceptor` only surrounded part of the condition ? Impossible to tell until a source to that library is provided

Comment: @T.S. or it could be that `GetQuery` call. Maybe it adds a `.Where(m=>m.Deleted=false)` to its predicate? Or not? Impossible to tell until the OP posts the code

Comment: @everybody you're all right I have to tell you more

So GetQuery is implemented like:
    context.Table.Where(predicate);
context is DbContext
Table if DbSet

And the softdeleteinterceptor:
    var binding = expression.Bind();
        return binding.Filter(
            binding.VariableType
                .Variable(binding.VariableName)
                .Property(IsDeletedColumnName)
                .NotEqual(DbExpression.FromBoolean(true)));

expression is DbScanExpression, so this is my GetQuery before call to db.

This is common implementation which u can find in google.